# How to export a file into a different directory using Python?

Tags: python, path, export

I'm trying to save myself from performing the old copy and past trick when saving files that Python generates.  The default is saving to the Python directory, however I would like it to be: C:\Program Files\Vixen\Vixen 2.1.1.0\Routines

I have tried this:

```
import os
filename = raw_input('What would you like to name the file? ')
filepath = os.path.join("C:\Program Files\Vixen\Vixen 2.1.1.0\Routines",filename)
with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
    for frame in frames:
        out.write(' '.join(str(num) for num in frame))
        out.write(' ')
        out.write('\n')
```

And the error I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1 in (module)
  File "comet.py", line 169, in (module)
    filepath= os.path.join("C:\Program Files\Vixen\Vixen 2.1.1.0\Routines",filename)
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

How can I get Python to save the file directly into the desired path?

Comment: I've done "import os", however, it's still saving to the python directory.

Comment: That's not what you said. You said it doesn't save and you get that error.

Comment: Of course its saving to the Python directory. You open `filename`, not `filepath`. BTW, please use raw strings in your path or escape the backslash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to load the os library. You can do that with `import os` prior to your code.

Edit: Another problem is that you are defining the path variable but are not using it anywhere apart from the assignment.
Try to change the following:

`with open(filename, 'wb') as out:` to `with open(filepath, 'wb') as out:`

Comment: I have added that to the code and it still saves in the python directory.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I've been staring at this for half an hour!